# Не открывается xls файл

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Мне надо распарсить xls таблицу. Скачал PHPOffice (но без композера) [отсюда](https://php-download.com/package/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet#all-versions) и пишу так:

```
require_once 'phpoffice_phpspreadsheet_1.10.1.0_require/index.php';

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('data.xls');
```

И скрипт у меня намертво повисает на вызове `load`. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать композер?

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка потому что так построен цикл разработки. Все правки через FTP, доступа по SSH нет, да и композера на сервере тоже. Знаю, что не комильфо, но это не я придумал.

Comment: Скачано отсюда https://shorturl.at/izLY9, в архиве уже сгенерированный файл композера, все прекрасно заработало  - https://pastebin.com/DSDDMhpz

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка первая ссылка не работает( Перекидывает на главную страницу

Comment: Попробуйте эту ссылку - https://yadi.sk/d/jbpTl3RW0AwVdA

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка а где вы его взяли? Там же где и я? Ну и какая разница тогда? Это же тот же самый архив... Все также не работает. Блин, может у меня с файлом что-то не так? У меня тут на компе только очень старый MS Office 2003 и нет возможности поставить ничего другого. =( Но он этот файл открывает и сохраняет нормально.

Comment: у вас там в роде примеры есть даже в документации https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/Examples/Reading%20WorkBook%20Data/exampleWorkBookReader01.php почему вы без фабрики создаете?

Comment: @teran а смысл? Фабрика просто сама определяет формат. Это замедляет скрипт. Если я точно знаю что на входе будет только один формат, то можно и конкретизировать... Кстати этот пример я тоже взял из документации.

Comment: спасибо, я в целом представляю, что фабрика сама определяет. А еще я знаю, что xls и xlsx файлы это принципиально разные форматы хранения. первый - бинарный, второй - xml, поэтому и интересуюсь.

Comment: каков объём файла data.xls ? В Мб и число строк